# Elasticsearch date range aggregation over multiple fields

Tags: date, elasticsearch

My documents' structure look like this:

```
{
    "element": "A",
    "date": "2014-01-01",
    "valid_until": "2014-02-01"
},
{
    "element": "A",
    "date": "2014-02-01",
    "valid_until": "9999-12-31"
}
```

The date "9999-12-31" is here to say: "it has not yet expired". There is always range like this, so for a given element "A", date > valid_until can never overlaps. I can therefore count how much element I have by using the pseudo-code like this: COUNT elements WHERE date < date_to_count AND valid_until >= date_to_count

Where "date_to_count" is the date at which I want to count the values for. As I want to calculate this at several points in time, I could either use a date histogram, or a date range aggregation. However, the date range does seem to work only with one kind of field. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do that:

```
"aggs": {
   "foo": {
       "date_range": {
          "fields": ["date", "valid_until"],
          "ranges": [
              {"from": "2014-01-01", "to": {"2014-02-01"}},
              {"from": "2014-02-01", "to": {"2014-03-01"}},
              {"from": "2014-03-01", "to": {"2014-04-01"}}
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

Where the "date" will be used for "from", and the "valid_until" would be used for "to".

I've tried several other ideas with script, but can't find an efficient way to do it this way :/.

I think I could also workaround this if, in a script, I could have access to the current from/to values, but once again, I've tried things like "ctx.to", "context.to", but those variables are undefined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since both the `date_range` and `date_histogram` aggregations work on a single field, I do not think you can achieve your goal with an aggregation. But if you don't have too many date ranges that you need to query for, you could call the [count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-count.html) with a query for each date range. That would look something like this:

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "bool" {
        "must": [
          { "range": { "date": { "gte": "2014-01-01" }}},
          { "range": { "valid_until": { "lt": "2014-02-01" }}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and wanted to address this by using one single query. Here is the solution that works for me in Elasticsearch 5.2

```
"aggs": {
   "range1": {
       "date_range": {
          "fields": "date",
          "ranges": [
              {"from": "2014-01-01", "to": {"2014-02-01"}},
              {"from": "2014-02-01", "to": {"2014-03-01"}},
              {"from": "2014-03-01", "to": {"2014-04-01"}}
          ]
       },
   "range2": {
       "date_range": {
          "field": "valid_until",
          "ranges": [
              {"from": "2014-01-01", "to": {"2014-02-01"}},
              {"from": "2014-02-01", "to": {"2014-03-01"}},
              {"from": "2014-03-01", "to": {"2014-04-01"}}
          ]
       }
   }
}
```